# how to build a json array with custom elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using JavaScript, I have an array:

```
[
  { "id": "0", "name": "test1", "brand": "brand1" },
  { "id": "0", "name": "test1", "brand": "brand2" },
  { "id": "0", "name": "test1", "brand": "brand3" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "test2", "brand": "brand100" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "test2", "brand": "brand101" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "test2", "brand": "brand102" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "test2", "brand": "brand103" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "test2", "brand": "brand104" }
]
```

I'm using JavaScript to have something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "name": "test1",
    "brand": [
      "brand1",
      "brand2",
      "brand3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test2",
    "brand": [
      "brand100",
      "brand101",
      "brand102",
      "brand103",
      "brand104"
    ]
  }
]
```

The script is:

```
let result=[]
for (var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++) {
let id =brands[i].id
    if(i==0){

        result.push(

          {
          "id": brands[i].id,
          "name": brands[i].name, 
           } )
 else{
        result.push(
           "id": brands[i].id,
          "name": brands[i].name )
    }
}
```

But it seems that it doesn't work...?

Comment: "json array" it's either a JSON fomatted string or it's an array.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything useful. What specifically is wrong? What have you done to diagnose the problem?

Comment: if you want I can give an answer with reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an object for the obj3ects with same `id` and get all values of it as result;

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "0", name: "test1", brand: "brand1" }, { id: "0", name: "test1", brand: "brand2" }, { id: "0", name: "test1", brand: "brand3" }, { id: "2", name: "test2", brand: "brand100" }, { id: "2", name: "test2", brand: "brand101" }, { id: "2", name: "test2", brand: "brand102" }, { id: "2", name: "test2", brand: "brand103" }, { id: "2", name: "test2", brand: "brand104" }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { id, name, brand }) => (
        (r[id] ??= { id, name, brand: [] }).brand.push(brand),
        r
    ), {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but it give me a syntaxError : unexpected token '??='

Comment: Is this norla ? when I copy past yu code on my vs code code it gives this error

Comment: you could replace `r[id] ??= { id, name, brand: [] }` with `r[id] = r[id] || { id, name, brand: [] }`.

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax problems in your code (You have missed brackets). Here is a fixed one:

```
let result = []
for (var i = 0; i < brands.length; i++) {
    let id = brands[i].id
    if (i == 0) {
        result.push({
            "id": brands[i].id,
            "name": brands[i].name,
        });
    } else {
        result.push({
            "id": brands[i].id,
            "name": brands[i].name
        });
    }
}
```